# Foreach vs IEnumerable.Concat() efficiency

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to add items to a dictionary in groups for each item in the assemblyPaths collection.

My question is which is the fastest method to add to the resulting Dictionary? Method 1 or Method 2(see code below). For method 1 I am using Concat to merge the newly created Dictionary with the master one(pluginTypes). For Method 2 I am using a simple foreach to add to the master Dictionary for each sub Dictionary. Is there really a difference in performance for the two different methods?

```
Dictionary<Type, string> pluginTypes = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

foreach (string assemblyPath in assemblyPaths)
{

Assembly assembly = RuntimeContext.Current.LoadAssembly(assemblyPath);

var plugins = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                let attribs = type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                where attribs.Select(x => (x as Attribute).GetType().FullName).Contains("PluginAttribute")
                select type)
                .ToDictionary(k => k, v => assemblyPath);

  // METHOD 1
  pluginTypes = pluginTypes
  .Concat(plugins)
  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

  // METHOD 2
  foreach (Type type in plugins.Keys)
     pluginTypes.Add(type, plugins[type]);

}
```

Personally, I like Method 1 better.

Comment: Why are you asking us which is faster, [when you could just test it](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: @Selman22 it's only empty in the first iteration of the loop..

Comment: `attribs.Select(x => (x as Attribute).GetType().FullName).Contains("PluginAttribute")` Please don't do that! Compare on the type instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should measure them to be certain, but *just by looking* I would suspect that Method 2 is faster for the following reasons:

1. `Concat` will enumerate the original dictionary which is unnecessary
2. `ToDictionary` will create a *new* dictionary by traversing the concatenated items from both objects.

Method 2 is cleaner, will use less memory, and is *probably* faster.

As a side note, you don't need to create the intermediate dictionary as part of the query; you can just reference the query results themselves when you add to the dictionary:

```
var plugins = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                let attribs = type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                where attribs.Select(x => (x as Attribute).GetType().FullName).Contains("PluginAttribute")
                select type)

  foreach (Type type in plugins)
     pluginTypes.Add(type, assemblyPath);
```

Comment: My code originally was using Method 2 (like your sample above). I only added the intermediate dictionary to implement Method 1. Your above code is actually identical to my original code. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim You could probably do it all in one linq statement (including the `foreach` on `assemblyPaths`) but it would be messy and difficult to debug. (and probably wouldn't buy you any speed improvement either).

Answer (score 2):

Without actually testing the two methods (which is, of course, always the best ways), one can try to attack the method logically.

Method 2 takes an existing collection, and adds a few new items to it.

Method 1 plucks all the elements out of two different collections, and builds an entirely new collections out of them.

It would seem to me that method 1 is doing about 3 times as much work --- on the first iteration. After that, it becomes four times as much work, then 5 times as much, as you pull more things out of `pluginTypes` and build a new dictionary out of them.

In fact, why are you building `plugins`  as a dictionary anway?  You're just pulling the items out linearly....

What you really want is something like:

```
 Assembly assembly = RuntimeContext.Current.LoadAssembly(assemblyPath);
 foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
 {
   if (type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
           .Select(x => (x as Attribute).GetType().FullName).Contains("PluginAttribute"))
      pluginTypes.Add(type, assemblyPath);
 }
```

Furtther, we need to ask, what exactly are we looking for amongst the custome attributes?  A attribute named exactly "PluginAttribute"? An attribute which contains "PluginAttribute" in it's name (such as "WidgetPluginAttribute")?  An attribute *derived* from PluginAttribute?.  My guess is the last is probably closest, so let's go with that.

```
 foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
 {
   if (type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Any(ca=> typeof(PluginAttribute).IsAssignablefrom(ca.GetType())))
      pluginTypes.Add(type, assemblyPath);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really thinking about how Concat and ToDictionary were actually working working. Testing it at this point is a bit difficult because I don't have a large collection of plugins to test. The contents of "assembyPath" is very small for my test environment.

Answer (score 2):

Before considering performance, please think about the following:

- You are creating a `Dictionary<Type, string>` where the value can be accessed from the key itself (using `Type.Assembly.Location`), hence having a dictionary does not make sense.
- If you have a class `PluginAttribute` defined, you can compare on that instead

E.g. this code:

```
private ISet<Type> GetTypes(IEnumerable<string> assemblyPaths)
{
    return new HashSet<Type>(assemblyPaths
        .Select(RuntimeContext.Current.LoadAssembly)
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<PluginTypeAttribute>() != null));
}
```

Or use `IList`, depending on if you want to iterate or use it in a dictionary-ish fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 should generally be faster. `ToDictionary` will basically always re-create the dictionary as `Concat` returns an `IEnumerable`. Why go again from existing dictionaries to `IEnumerable`  just to re-create the dictionary?

Careful if you don't have unique keys, you might get an exception in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really sure how ToDictionary worked in the background. Same for Concat. As for the unique keys in the dictionary it doesn't seem to matter. It seems that determining if a key is unique when the key is of type Type it doesn't seem to matter if the exact same type is added again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LINQ operation that specifically takes a sequence of items, projects each item into a new sequence, and then returns a sequence representing all of the projected sequences concatted together.  That operation is `SelectMany`.  Your variation of it, in which you use `Concat` on each of those queries, is semantically identical, but results in a lot of additional levels of indirection, and a lot of needless overhead.

On top of all of that, you are constantly creating and then throwing away dictionaries each time you iterate through your outer loop.  Since the construction of a dictionary is time and memory consuming, this is going to have significant negative performance repercussions.

Your second solution does remove some of these unnecessary overheads, and it does so through mutating an object rather than through using query operations.  That doesn't meant that you can't use query operations to efficiently solve this problem though, you just need to use the right ones.

```
Dictionary<Type, string> pluginTypes =
    (from assemblyPath in assemblyPaths
        let assembly = RuntimeContext.Current.LoadAssembly(assemblyPath)
        from type in assembly.GetTypes()
        let attribs = type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
        where attribs.Select(x => (x as Attribute).GetType().FullName)
        .Contains("PluginAttribute")
        select new
        {
            key = type,
            value = assemblyPath
        })
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.value);
```